# How to enable Additive Blending in A-Frame?

Tags: 3d, aframe, blending, webvr

What is the easiest way to enable Additive Blending in A-Frame? I see that the `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial` has a `blending` property which looks like what I need, but it is not exposed by the A-Frame `material` component.

Do I have to write a custom component to get the entity's material and set this property myself? It seems like this common requirement should already be catered for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A-Frame 0.9.0 and above:**

A-Frame now supports the `blending` property from version 0.9.0 and up. See https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#properties_blending

**A-Frame 0.8.0 and older:**

I went ahead and created my own Blend Mode component for this:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('blendmode', {
  schema: {
    mode: {default: 'AdditiveBlending'} //Available Modes are: var blendings = [ "NoBlending", "NormalBlending", "AdditiveBlending", "SubtractiveBlending", "MultiplyBlending" ];
  },

    dependencies: ['material'],

  update: function () {
    // entity data
    var el = this.el;
    var data = this.data;

      if (el.components.hasOwnProperty("material")) {
          var mat = el.components.material.material;
          mat.blending = THREE[data.mode];
      }
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice solution! Short components like this are generally what I've done, but perhaps it's worth a PR to support the `blending` option. Also note that if the  entity does *not* already have a `material` component, that `dependencies` entry will add it (as of A-Frame 0.5.0, I think).

Comment: A way around it would be `el.getObject3D('mesh').material`, or listening for the `object3dset` event to know when a mesh has loaded from a model.

Comment: More recent version of A-Frame includes `blending` property on core material component:
https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/components/material.html#properties_blending

Comment: @KieranF. Thanks, I updated my answer to reflect this.